# Excel file (.xlsx) created by using DocumentFormat.OpenXML needs to be repaired when opening in Excel

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

I have a method which create an excel file (.xlsx) from a list of strings using DocumentFormat.OpenXml. The created file needs to be repaired when I try to open it with Excel 2016. When I click "Yes" Excel shows my file correctly.
Does anyone have any suggestions? Thanks in advance.

Here's my code:

```
private byte[] ExportDataXlsx(System.Data.Common.DbDataReader reader, string[] fields, string[] headers, string Culture) {
  System.IO.MemoryStream sw = new System.IO.MemoryStream();
  using (var workbook = Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument.Create(sw, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook)) {
      
      var sheetData = CreateSheet(workbook);

      while (reader.Read()) {
          Spreadsheet.Row newRow = new Spreadsheet.Row();
          foreach (string column in fields) {
              Spreadsheet.Cell cell = new Spreadsheet.Cell();
              cell.DataType = Spreadsheet.CellValues.String;
              object value = null;
              try {
                  int index = reader.GetOrdinal(column);
                  cell.DataType = DbKymosDomainService.ToXlsType(reader.GetFieldType(index));

                  value = DbKymosDomainService.ToStringFromCulture(reader.GetValue(index), reader.GetFieldType(index), Culture);
                  if (cell.DataType == Spreadsheet.CellValues.Number){
                      value = value == null ? "" : value.ToString().Replace(",", ".");
                  }
              }
              catch { }
              cell.CellValue = new Spreadsheet.CellValue(value == null ? null : value.ToString()); //
              newRow.AppendChild(cell);
              try { var x = newRow.InnerXml; } catch { newRow.RemoveChild(cell); }
          }

          sheetData.AppendChild(newRow);
      }

      workbook.Close();
  }

  byte[] data = sw.ToArray();
  sw.Close();
  sw.Dispose();

  return data;
}
```

Function which create sheet:

```
private Spreadsheet.SheetData CreateSheet(Packaging.SpreadsheetDocument workbook)
{
    var workbookPart = workbook.AddWorkbookPart();

    workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook = new Spreadsheet.Workbook();

    workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.Sheets = new Spreadsheet.Sheets();

    var sheetPart = workbook.WorkbookPart.AddNewPart<Packaging.WorksheetPart>();
    var sheetData = new Spreadsheet.SheetData();
    sheetPart.Worksheet = new Spreadsheet.Worksheet(sheetData);

    Spreadsheet.Sheets sheets = workbook.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Spreadsheet.Sheets>();
    string relationshipId = workbook.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(sheetPart);

    uint sheetId = 1;
    if (sheets.Elements<Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Count() > 0) {
        sheetId =
            sheets.Elements<Spreadsheet.Sheet>().Select(s => s.SheetId.Value).Max() + 1;
    }

    Spreadsheet.Sheet sheet = new Spreadsheet.Sheet() { Id = relationshipId, SheetId = sheetId, Name = "Export" };
    sheets.Append(sheet);

    return sheetData;
}
```

Comment: I'd create the same thing through the application and then compare the generated XML to see where differences might be occurring that might be causing your issue.  It's a thought.

Comment: There's a lot of code there: it's likely that noone is going to be able to read through it and spot your error. Take out bits of code and see where it stops being broken -- that is, create a [mcve], with the emphasis on **minimal**. Your code should not contain anything which can be removed, and still reproduce the problem

Comment: @Skin Already done. Excel create a new folder 'docProps' under root and 'theme' under xl. It create new files also, like 'sharedString.xml' and 'styles.xml' under folder 'xl'.

Comment: @SimoneUrbani instead of working with the low-level Open XML API use a library like EPPlus or ClosedXML. All this code could be reduced to just `sheet.Cells.LoadFromDataReader(someDbReader);` or `LoadFromCollection(someItems)` in EPPlus

Comment: Seconded -- while the Word OpenXML format is reasonably easy to work with, the Excel OpenXML format is full of pitfalls and minefields. That's why there are some good helpers, see the [list provided by the OpenXML SDK authors themselves](https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK#related-tools)

Answer (score 2):

In my experience when a file needs to be repaired after creating it using OpenXML it means that it is missing a crucial element or the crucial element is in the wrong place. I'm having difficulty following your code so that in itself points to something being in the wrong place. Code should be sequential and self-explanatory. A few pointers however to help with getting to the root cause of your issue.

I would suggest first using ClosedXML as it takes so much strain out of the coding.https://github.com/closedxml/closedxml

Debug your code and step through each step to see what's going on.

Open the created file in OpenXML Productivity Tool https://github.com/OfficeDev/Open-XML-SDK/releases/tag/v2.5 and have a look around.

Another tool that I couldn't be without is OpenXML FileViewer: https://github.com/davecra/OpenXmlFileViewer

Lastly I always run this sub routine to validate documents I create using OpenXML:

```
    public static List<string> ValidateWordDocument(FileInfo filepath, ref Int32 maxerrors = 100)
{
    try
    {
        using (WordprocessingDocument wDoc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(filepath.FullName, false))
        {
            OpenXmlValidator validator = new OpenXmlValidator();
            int count = 0;
            List<string> er = new List<string>()
            {
                string.Format($"Assessment of {filepath.Name} on {DateTime.Now} yielded the following result:  {Constants.vbCrLf}")
            };

            // set at zero so that we can determine the total quantity of errors
            validator.MaxNumberOfErrors = 0;
            // String.Format("<strong> Warning : </strong>")
            foreach (ValidationErrorInfo error in validator.Validate(wDoc))
            {
                count += 1;
                if (count > maxerrors)
                    break;
                er.Add($"Error {count}{Constants.vbCrLf}" +  $"Description {error.Description}{Constants.vbCrLf}" + $"ErrorType:  {error.ErrorType}{Constants.vbCrLf}" + $"Node {error.Node}{Constants.vbCrLf}" + $"Name {error.Node.LocalName}{Constants.vbCrLf}" + $"Path {error.Path.XPath}{Constants.vbCrLf}" + $"Part: {error.Part.Uri}{Constants.vbCrLf}" + $"-------------------------------------------{Constants.vbCrLf}" + $"Outer XML: {error.Node.OuterXml}" + $"-------------------------------------------{Constants.vbCrLf}");
            }
            int validatorcount = validator.Validate(wDoc).Count;

            switch (validatorcount)
            {
                case object _ when validatorcount > maxerrors:
                    {
                        er.Add($"Returned {count - 1} as this is the Maximum Number set by the system. The actual number of errors in {filepath.Name} is {validatorcount}");
                        er.Add("A summary list of all error types encountered is given below");

                        List<string> expectedErrors = validator.Validate(wDoc).Select(_e => _e.Description).Distinct().ToList();
                        er.AddRange(expectedErrors);
                        break;
                    }

                case object _ when 1 <= validatorcount && validatorcount <= maxerrors:
                    {
                        er.Add($"Returned all {validator}  errors in {filepath.Name}");
                        break;
                    }

                case object _ when validatorcount == 0:
                    {
                        er.Add($"No Errors found in document {filepath.Name}");
                        break;
                    }
            }

            return er;

            wDoc.Close();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Information.Err.MessageElevate();
        return null;
    }
}
```

It helps greatly with problem solving any potential issues.